# Should git ls-files list the files being tracked by LFS (git lfs ls-files)

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-ls-files

I'm hoping this is a simple question - will `git ls-files` list the files I see from running `git lfs ls-files`? Or, are they managed and hence listed separately.

This is the first time I've used LFS, I've an error appearing but before I dive into that I want to check some basics, and I can't find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Iain. You're misreading the ethos of Be Nice. The point of that project was to try to reduce abruptness and snark directed at newcomers, and that eventually became [the Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). However, for the time being, [the desire to aim for technical writing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) is unchanged. There was some musing from the company about relaxing the "no fluff" guideline, but the Welcoming Initiative kicked up such a hornet's nest, I doubt the company would go for it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git itself treats LFS files as pointer files. So, it will list them in `git ls-files` if they are committed to the repository.

You can read more about pointer files [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#lfs-pointer-files-advanced).